# Error when using try catch in Java

Tags: java

I am facing problems when using try/catch

I created an exception class called EmptyQueueException that extends from Exception

Unfortunately, Eclipse throws me an error :" Catched expected instead"

```
public class Testclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayQueue arrayy = new ArrayQueue();
        try{
            arrayy.dequeue();
          } 
        catch(EmptyQueueException s){
               // what to do here ?     
        }
    } // end main
} // end testclass
```

Here is my Exception class:

```
   public class EmptyQueueException extends Exception {

    // automatically done by eclipse, what for?
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    public EmptyQueueException() {
    }

    public EmptyQueueException(String s){
        super("Queue is empty");
    }
}
```

This is my dequeue method:

```
  public int dequeue() throws EmptyQueueException {
    if (empty()){
        throw new EmptyQueueException();
    }
    int retour = head();
    head = ++head % array.length;
    return retour;
}
```

Comment: Eclipse throws me an error when trying this: What is that?

Comment: `dequeue()` method throws `EmptyQueueException`??

Comment: What does `arrayy.dequeue()` throw? If it doesn't thorw EmptyQueueException, your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Well, I try to executed dequeue(), but I want to catch the case when the queue is empty, therefore "EmptyQueueException". I can not return anything when the stack is empty.

Comment: Eclipse does not *throw* errors, but you can have compilation errors. Anyway, relevant information to potential helpers is: *what is the error message?*

Comment: I added my dequeue method, please look again.

Comment: The compiler guys did the implementing. You are just using.

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but the EmptyQueueException constructor that gets a String should probably pass it to the super class, and the one that doesn't have any parameters should pass the default "Queue is empty" message to super.

Comment: does this code compile? or is this a runtime error?